# Given an array of positive integers. Divide it into 2 arrays where avg of each array is same

Tags: java, algorithm, java-8, dynamic-programming

Example:

**[1,2,4,5] output would be [1,5] and [2,4]**

So here is what I tried but code breaks at one point need help with decision making at that point.From below code **if(avgArr1 < avgArr2){** is the point where I decide which needs to be the source array which needs to be destination array for inserting and deleting elements. This condition is not reliable and empties one of the array.

```
package test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class ArrayAvg {
    static int[] arr1;
    static int[] arr2;
    public Map<String,int[]> swap(int[] src,int[] dest,int num,boolean swapLeft){
        Map<String,int[]> arrMap = new HashMap<String,int[]>();
        System.out.println("num"+num);
        ///System.out.println(Arrays.toString(src));
        ///System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dest));
        int[] tempL;
        int[] tempR;
        int myNumber = num;
        int distance = Math.abs(src[0] - myNumber);
        int idx = 0;
        for(int c = 1; c < src.length; c++){
            int cdistance = Math.abs(src[c] - myNumber);
            if(cdistance < distance){
                idx = c;
                distance = cdistance;
            }
        }
        int theNumber = src[idx];
        System.out.println("the num"+theNumber);
        if(swapLeft){
            tempL= new int[dest.length+1];
            tempR= new int[src.length-1];
            tempR = Arrays.stream( src ).filter( value -> value != theNumber ).toArray();
            //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tempR));
            tempL = Arrays.copyOf(dest, dest.length+1);//Range(dest, 0, src.length);
            tempL[tempL.length-1] = theNumber;
            //*/System.arraycopy(dest, 0, tempL, 1, 2);*/
            //System.out.println(tempL.length+1);
            //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tempL));
            arr1 = tempL;
            arr2 = tempR;
        }else{
            tempL= new int[src.length-1];
            tempR= new int[dest.length+1];
            tempR = Arrays.stream( src ).filter( value -> value != theNumber ).toArray();
            tempL = Arrays.copyOfRange(dest, 0, src.length);
            tempL[tempL.length-1] = num;
            arr1 = tempR;
            arr2 = tempL;
        }
        /*dest = tempL;
        src = tempR;*/
        arrMap.put("arr1", arr1);
        arrMap.put("arr2", arr2);
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tempL));
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr1));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr1));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr2));
        //System.arraycopy(temp, 0, dest, 0, temp.length);
        return  arrMap;
    }
    public void printArr(int[] arr,int[] arr1,int[] arr2){
        Arrays.sort(arr1);
        Arrays.sort(arr2);

        double avgArr1 = IntStream.of(arr1).sum()/arr1.length;
        double avgArr2 = IntStream.of(arr2).sum()/arr2.length;
        while(avgArr1 != avgArr2){
            int arrAvg = (int) (avgArr1 + avgArr2)/2;
            int nearestValue = (arrAvg/2);
            System.out.println(arrAvg);
            Map<String,int[]> res;
            if(avgArr1 < avgArr2){
                res = swap(arr2,arr1,nearestValue,true);
            }else{
                res = swap(arr1,arr2,nearestValue,false);
            }
            arr1 = res.get("arr1");
            arr2 = res.get("arr2");
            avgArr1 = IntStream.of(arr1).sum()/arr1.length;
            avgArr2 = IntStream.of(arr2).sum()/arr2.length;
            Arrays.sort(arr1);
            Arrays.sort(arr2);
        }
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr1));
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr2));
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int [] intarr = {1,2,5,4};
        Arrays.sort(intarr);
        //ArrayAvg.printArr(intarr); 
        arr1 = Arrays.copyOfRange(intarr, 0, intarr.length/2);
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        arr2 = Arrays.copyOfRange(intarr, (intarr.length/2), intarr.length);
        new ArrayAvg().printArr(intarr,arr1,arr2);
        //System.out.println(intarr);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not necessarily possible for every array of numbers ... for example, it is not possible to divide `[1, 2, 5]` or `[1, 2, 1000, 10000]` into subsets with equal means. What should the solution do in such cases?

Comment: In case of no solution it should return no solution found though have not handled that in above code.

Comment: As an aside, `IntStream` has an `average` method, so if you're sure the arrays will never be empty then you can do `double avgArr1 = IntStream.of(arr1).average().getAsDouble();`  otherwise use the Optional methods to decide upon the appropriate action in the case of an empty array. avoid `IntStream.of(arr1).sum()/arr1.length;`

Answer (score 0):

This problem might be solved with dynamic programming. Make a table with size OverallSum. Fill it with all possible subsets sums, recording also number of items and the last item used to make every sum.

Let average of whole array is `A = P/Q`(rational value, `GCD(P,Q)=1`). Now check whether sums `P, 2P, 3P... kP`  might be created from `Q, 2Q, 3Q...kQ` items. If yes, unwind sum to get items composing this sum

For example  `[1, 2, 5, 6]  A = 3.5 = 7/2` so check if **sum 7** might be composed **from two items**

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in solutions where the average in both parts is identical, that means both parts must have either (1) only the target average as a member(s) or (2) both a set of lower than average and a set of higher than average numbers.

Furthermore, if

```
a / b = c / d
```

then

```
a / b = (a + c) / (b + d)
```

So what you are looking for is a partition, where each part's sum is a multiple of the average of the whole list. We can divide and conquer to at least split our subset sum search to those made from either exclusively elements smaller than or exclusively elements greater than the average of the whole list.

Let `A` be the average of the whole list. If there are any elements in the list equal to A, splitting off any number of these into one part would constitute a valid solution.

Otherwise, let `sh` and `sl` be the sum of a subset of elements all higher than `A` and the sum of a subset of elements all less than `A`, respectively; and `kh` and `kl` these subsets' respective cardinalities. Then:

```
(sh + sl) / (kh + kl) = A
```

So given any sum and cardinality for a subset of elements lower than `A`, `(sl, kl)`, a matching tuple of elements higher than `A` would have to equal a constant:

```
sh = A * (kh + kl) - sl

sh - A * kh = A * kl - sl
```

We can store and look up `sh - A * kh` (and similarly for the lower tuples).

#### Example:

```
[1,2,4,5]
A = 3
```

Either of `[1,5]` or `[2,4]` would inform us that a solution exists. We only need to find *one* of them.

```
sh - A * kh  =  A * kl - sl

5  - 3 * 1   =  3 * 1  - 1
4  - 3 * 1   =  3 * 1  - 2
```